# How to print a 6* 6 grid as described below in Python

Tags: python-2.7

[image]

How can i print a grid as shown below without any contents:
I tried the below input:

```
grid = [["|" for x in range(7)] for y in range(6)]
for row in grid:
    print(" ".join(row))
```

But it generated the below output:

```
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
```

I can't think of how to connect the empty spaces with _. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
grid = [[" _" for x in range(6)]]
for y in range(6):
    list1 = []
    for x in range(13):
        if x%2 == 0:
            list1.append("|")
        else:
            list1.append("_")
    grid.append(list1)

for row in grid:
    print("".join(row))
```

output:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Comment: thanks this works,could you tell me how to place the tile on a specific location in this grid.

Comment: @Dkk need to change the grid to place a tile as every position is occupied by "_" in the grid